# Requests: Unexpected error_verify_payment when there are no drivers available

Tags: uber-api

We have been testing the [Request API](https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/api/v1-requests) and identified that when we test requests for a car type (say Uber XL) in an area in which you report on the Uber App that there are no cars (we tested in Luton) we have no way of conveying this to users of our App since we get an error (see below) and cannot go through to booking a car and getting the No Drivers Available state.

The error we get is:

error_verify_payment
Please visit your account settings and re-enter one of the existing payment methods by tapping "Add Payment". If there are any issues, please reach out to support@uber.com.

We need guidance from you how to overcome this error as we cannot reliably tell our users at the moment that there are no cars.

Thanks!

Comment: Would you please share some code including the endpoints you call? I just made a [/v1/products](https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/api/v1-products) call for [Luton](https://www.google.com/maps/place/51%C2%B052'48.6%22N+0%C2%B024'40.0%22W/@51.8801693,-0.4132917,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d51.880166!4d-0.411103?hl=en) and got 4 products (UberX, UberXL,...). Based on your error message, I'd assume that the payment method verification is the core issue. Did you reach out to support@uber.com to solve that issue for your specific/authenticated user account?

Comment: Hi, could you check that you have tested in an area that specifically doesn't have Ubers available (as can be verified in the Uber app so that you get "No drivers available" there)? The /v1/requests works just fine for us when there are cars in that area, indicating that there is no underlying account issue. Our Uber integration seems to work perfectly other than this issue, and we have done various tests on other endpoints with multiple accounts. We have indeed contacted that email address, but it seems to be out of use since we were directed to post a question here. Thanks for the help.